# Как в Yii2 добавить методы к классу yii\base\Model?

Tags: php, yii2

Добрый день!

Как в Yii2 добавить методы к классу `yii\base\Model`, так, чтобы все потомки, которые наследуют от него (например `yii\db\ActiveRecord`), также видели эти методы?

Answer (score 2):

Лучше всего создать свой класс app\models\AppBaseModel на основе yii\base\Model и наследовать от него все свои классы приложения.

Answer (score 1):

Если не вносить изменения в существующий базовый класс, то никак.

В качестве альтернативы:

- Реализовать методы в [trait](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.traits.php)
- Реализовать методы в [behavior](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-behaviors.html) и подключить его в необходимые модели

Кроме того, можно создать новый базовый класс модели, который расширял бы существующий Model (или ActiveRecord)

Answer (score 1):

Вы так же можете попробовать использовать Yii::$classMap, но нужно сделать копию Model, расширить его методами, и указать его в $classMap

```
Yii::$classMap['yii\base\Model'] = 'path/to/MyModel.php';
```

(http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-autoloading.html)

не лучший вариант, лучше предложили ранее.